# Direct integration of Taylor series and Gauss Quadrature

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, numerical-calculus

The most common approach to the numerical integration of function f(x) I have seen in articles is the Gauss quadrature formula, even if the function is analytic on the interval in which it needs to be integrated. However, many special functions I have observed are calculated through their Taylor series expansions. Why and when is it wiser to use the quadrature formula instead of the Taylor series expansion? Or in other words, when does the Taylor series fail (considering the closed interval inside the circle of convergence), even though it is proven that the integration of analytic functions is polynomial time computable?
Edit: the question could be reformulated the following way - when it is more wise to use Taylor series expansion for numerical integration instead of quadrature?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the function is truly analytic in the region and could be extended a little bit to outside, then quadrature rule and expansion should be both good enough. The special functions usually have a very "easy-computing" expansion, if the expansion converges fast, then it is easier to do integration in expansion. Doing quadrature rule needs evaluation of at the nodes, which could be potentially expensive for special functions whose values are usually defined in a recursive way.

Comment: @Yimin, what is the lower bound to the rate or speed of convergence for the Taylor series inside closed interval within the circle of convergence?

Comment: It depends on the growth of the coefficient. The coefficient can be estimated by contour integral, if your function is analytic within a large region.